# Can I customize a CustomInput button from reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, customization, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap in my project, however when I try to use a custom input to upload a picture, the component  shows a button with the name "Browse", since I am creating a project in a different language, I need to change that "Browse" to "Another Word", I've reading the docs but did not find any solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the css property of content for `input` type:

```
.custom-file-label::after {
    content:"another word" !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, I tried that but it did not work :(

Comment: It is working for me can you please provide your code snippet with output next to it

Comment: Now i added `!important` next to `content` value please let me know whether it works or not